# Fatal error: Call to undefined method utilisateurCore::connect()

Tags: php, methods, undefined

I have a class named `utilisateurCore` when I call a method `connect` it displays to me an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method utilisateurCore::connect()"

while it's declared and defined in the class `utilisateurCore` and **utilisateurCore.php** is already included in the file where the error is (
(**connexion.php**) .

This is **utilisateurCore.php** ( where the method is defined )

```
  <?php 
    include "../config.php";
    class utilisateurCore{

     function inscritption($utilisateur)
     {
                $sql="insert into membres (pseudo,mail,motdepasse) values (:pseudo,:mail,:motdepasse)";
            $db = config::getConnexion();
            try{
            $req=$db->prepare($sql);

            $pseudo=$utilisateur->getPseudo();
            $mail=$utilisateur->getEmail();
            $motdepasse=$utilisateur->getMotdepasse();
            $req->bindValue(':pseudo',$pseudo);
            $req->bindValue(':mail',$mail);
            $req->bindValue(':motdepasse',$motdepasse);

                $req->execute();

            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                echo 'Erreur: '.$e->getMessage();
            }


    }

    function connect($utilisateur)
    {   
        $db = config::getConnexion();
        $mailconnect=$utilisateur->getPseudo();
        $mdpconnect=$utilisateur->getEmail();

          $requser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM membres WHERE mail = ? AND motdepasse = ?");
          $requser->execute(array($mailconnect, $mdpconnect));
          $userexist = $requser->rowCount();
    return $userexist;
    }

    }

    ?>
```

This is **connexion.php** where I called the method :

```
 <?php 
    include "../entities/utilisateur.php";
    include "../core/utilisateurCore.php";

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['formconnexion'])) {
       $mailconnect = $_POST['mailconnect'];
       $mdpconnect = $_POST['mdpconnect'];
       $empty="test";
       if(!empty($mailconnect) AND !empty($mdpconnect)) {

      $utilisateur1= new utilisateur($mailconnect,$mdpconnect,$empty);
      $utilisateur1C= new utilisateurCore(); 
      $userexist=$utilisateur1C->connect($utilisateur1);

          if($userexist == 1) {
             $userinfo = $requser->fetch();
             $_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo['id'];
             $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $userinfo['pseudo'];
             $_SESSION['mail'] = $userinfo['mail'];
             header("Location: profils.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']);
          } else {
             $erreur = "Mauvais mail ou mot de passe !";
          }
       } else {
          $erreur = "Tous les champs doivent être complétés !";
       }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Are you sure you posted the **actual** code you're trying to run?

Comment: yes it's the same code !! , the weird thing is that when i call the first function "inscription()" it detects it as a defined function but the second one "connect()" is undefined !!  is the definition of connect() in utilisateurCore.php defined in a right way ?

Comment: Yes, it's defined correctly. I know it because this code runs for me. Make sure you don't have multiple copies of `utilisateurCore.php`.

Comment: when i checked the existance of this method using this code :
$test=function_exists ( string $connection );
if($test==true)
{
    echo "true";
}
it's not returning true !

Comment: @GreatBigBore i have a copy of utilisateurCore.php but not in the same folder !

Comment: Does that copy have `connect()` in it?

Comment: thanks it's solved @GreatBigBore